# GNU Guix usb-install freezes at GRUB after boot

Tags: grub, dd, gnu, freeze, fat32

I wanted to try out the GNU usb install that was released with Guix 0.7. The problem is that when I try to boot from the USB, it freezes, with the word GRUB and a flashing type line. I followed the instructions. First I downloaded the compressed file from `wget http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/guix/gnu-usb-install-0.7.x86_64-linux.xz`, then I extracted it `xz gnu-usb-install-0.7.x86_64-linux.xz`, then I dd it onto my 64GB USB flash drive, which I formatted to FAT32 and added the boot flag prior to dd'ing it, as so `sudo dd if=gnu-usb-install-0.7.x86_64-linux of=/dev/sdb1`. And as I said before, when I go on the boot menu and choose to boot from the flash drive, it just shows `GRUB _`, and everytime I press a key it beeps.

Comment: on some uefi machines `grub` video hacks fail miserably and you wind up with a black screen or frozen framebuffer for some time. if the booting kernel does not properly handle GOP video init it will remain that way, though the OS actually does load. in other cases you get the `grub` rescue prompt and can do something with it. I'm not sure which problem - if either - you have. I can say that if you are formatting a disk then `dd`ing a file over it you are likely wasting your time with one or the other operation.

Comment: I tried to tboot the USB on 2 machines, one which used to be a Vista machine with AMD Graphics and ATI video card, I'm not sure about GNU support for that. So the latter problem might a good explanation for why it didn't work on that computer. But on the other one, which is a more recent i7 3rd Gen with GTX nvidia graphics card, should have worked becuase there is very good support for intel graphics by default and nouveau is pretty ok. There was UEFI on the machine, but I disabled it. And if formatting then dd'ing wastes time, it shouldn't make a problem.

Comment: you cannot *disable* uefi. it is the firmware. often you can *enable* the *compatibility support module* - but it only adds another layer of complexity. doing so does not necessarily mean the graphics module will support it. and yes format + `dd` shouldn't make a problem - *I think*. It is hard to know given the small level of detail you have related.

Comment: It doesn't say that in my BIOS. It gives me the option of disabling UEFI.

Comment: you don't have a bios. you have uefi. the option names don't mean much - they just mostly say what little they think they have to. uefi is a type of firmware. bios is another, older type. uefi firmwares often include *compatibility support modules* - which are *legacy modes* or whatever and are basically bios emulation layers - so that they may provide backwards-compatible support with bios dependent bootloaders/oses.

Comment: I have the older type, the bios. I am sure of it. I bought my computer pre-windows 8. And I did read all the firmware specs. And nothing said anything about uefi.

Comment: That's possible - but very little likely with an i7. uefi is intel's baby. windows 8 didn't have much to do with uefi except that ms required a win8 *certified* machine to have a uefi as opposed to a bios. a bios would not have a uefi-anything option, I think - though I could be wrong about that.

Comment: It would be possible that when I did a windows 8 installation on it oh so long ago that is uploaded that module to the firmware

Comment: no. you cannot upgrade a bios to uefi. there is one or there is the other. still, I think all of this is beside the point - I was saying only that it is entirely possible the os does boot behind that frozen framebuffer and you cannot see it.

Comment: Is there any way I can check if it did boot or not?

Comment: It is quite old question. In the newer version of the Guix documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/manual/html_node/USB-Stick-Installation.html#USB-Stick-Installation it is stated that you don't write in a USB drive partition. You directly write over the drive: `dd if=guixsd-usb-install-0.10.0.x86_64 of=/dev/sdX`.

Comment: Same phenomenon still happens to me with `0.13`, although it does not beep. Simply shows `GRUB _`, cannot do anything, except `ctrl+alt+del`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `/dev/sdb` instead of `/dev/sdb1` while using `dd` solved the problem for me.

```
sudo dd bs=32M if=gnu-usb-install-0.7.x86_64-linux of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: @nwildner it looks like it is a plausible answer, even if it's very short.